# I cannot change my hat on any of the SE sites!

Tags: bug, winter-bash, hats

Since 22nd December I cannot change or remove my hats. I get an error (screenshot below):

> An error occurred while changing the hat - please try again.

I have tried several operating systems and browsers. What can I do?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OMG!! You are reporting it today... Hats are about to disappear in less than 7.5 hours...